# Load spring configuration on startup with native image

Tags: spring-boot, docker, graalvm

Spring Boot can load property files from the jar directory as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.0.RC5/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)

However, this does not seem to work when building a native image using graalvm.

What I do ist build a native image using `bootBuildImage`.

I try to mount a example configruation into my docker container like this:

```
docker run -d -v application.yaml:/cnb/process/application.yaml <registry>/api-prober
```

I also tried

```
docker run -d -v application.yaml:/cnb/process/application.yml <registry>/api-prober
```

<strike>docker run -d -v application.yaml:/workspace/application.yml /api-prober</strike>

From what I can see, /cnb/process is the entrypoint and I assume the binary resides in this folder, however, the config does not get picked up.

How can I use externalized configuration with graalvm and spring boot?

**Edit**: The striked- through variant seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

In the link you mentioned in the question, SpringBoot will find for config file in **current** directory, not the jar directory. I reckon maybe the working directory in docker image is not the directory that jar exists.

Comment: I don't know which directory the executable resides in, I cannot find any information where bootBuildImage puts an executable to, do you know which directory might be the executable dir in a native image built by bootBuildImage?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, trial and error and typos I found out, that the default executable directory is

`/workspace`

so if you run it with

docker run -d -v application.yaml:/workspace/application.yml /api-prober

Spring picks up my config file on startup